# What is the best way to getting first character from array of object in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, nativescript

I wanna get the first character from each name inside an array
I used typescript with Nativescript and trying to get the first character from names to listview

```js
export function onNavigatingTo(args: EventData) {
        const page = <Page>args.object;
      
        
       let vm = fromObject({
            // Setting the listview binding source
           myTitles: [
                { name: "Vinci " , lastName: "ASDF1" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com"},
                { name: "Harry " , lastName: "ASDF2" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: " Alchemist  " , lastName: "ASDF3" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: " Godfather  "  , lastName: "ASDF4" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: "Goodnight " , lastName: "ASDF5" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com"},
                { name: "Hobbit ", lastName: "ASDF6", email: "waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: "Vinci " , lastName: "ASDF1" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com"},
                { name: "Harry " , lastName: "ASDF2" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: " Alchemist  " , lastName: "ASDF3" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: " Godfather  "  , lastName: "ASDF4" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: "Goodnight " , lastName: "ASDF5" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com"},
               { name: "Hobbit ", lastName: "ASDF6", email: "waelashi1@gmail.com" },
           ]
       });
        
        
       
        page.bindingContext = vm;
        
    }
    }
```

Comment: `const firstChars = original.map(elem => elem.name[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

Use the map function

```js
const obj = {
            // Setting the listview binding source
           myTitles: [
                { name: "Vinci " , lastName: "ASDF1" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com"},
                { name: "Harry " , lastName: "ASDF2" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: " Alchemist  " , lastName: "ASDF3" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: " Godfather  "  , lastName: "ASDF4" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: "Goodnight " , lastName: "ASDF5" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com"},
                { name: "Hobbit ", lastName: "ASDF6", email: "waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: "Vinci " , lastName: "ASDF1" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com"},
                { name: "Harry " , lastName: "ASDF2" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: " Alchemist  " , lastName: "ASDF3" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: " Godfather  "  , lastName: "ASDF4" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com" },
                { name: "Goodnight " , lastName: "ASDF5" , email:"waelashi1@gmail.com"},
               { name: "Hobbit ", lastName: "ASDF6", email: "waelashi1@gmail.com" },
           ]
       }

    console.log(obj.myTitles.map((title) => title.name[0]))
    // Removing extra space
    console.log(obj.myTitles.map((title) => title.name.trim()[0]))
```